# Jenkins auto build using CM Synergy

Tags: jenkins, build, cm-synergy

I am trying to set up an auto build using Jenkins. All I have to do is whenever there is a code change in the database, the automated build should happen and the build version should have the latest number. I saw all the websites using Jenkins with Git or other version control systems. I just want to have a clear picture about Jenkins and its complete details. Is there any possibility that I can use Jenkins with IBM Rational Synergy?

It would be great if i could get any available links or tutorials.

Comment: How do you plan to use Jenkins with `IBM DOORS`? I think that's a requirement management tool not a version control system. Do you mean `IBM Rational CM/Synergy`?

Comment: Yes its IBM Synergy . I wanted to use for version control system . IS that possible ??

Comment: Yes, very much! Check my answer. By the way, i wasn't sure that there was a Synergy client plugin. I used to administer Synergy in my first job. That time it was CM Synergy by Telelogic :)

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about Jenkins [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins). For build to automatically happen, you just have to enable `Poll SCM` option in `Build Triggers` section. You can check [this](http://jenkins-le-guide-complet.batmat.cloudbees.net/html/sect-first-steps-first-job.html) link which shows how to setup your job using `Poll SCM` option. You should also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577959/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-job-using-the-p4-plugin-or-p4/25579218#25579218) link for setting up `Quiet period` which is a good to enable when using Polling feature.

If you are using IBM Rational CM/Synergy, there is a [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Synergy+Plugin) for it. Install it and get going! :)

Comment: Thanks !! I will get back if I have any problem in setting up

Comment: @pranathi: Did you try the suggestion?